pip or conda, how to check which was used?
I know "pip" and "conda" are two methods that install dependencies during program development and similar scenarios. And the difference between them is that "conda" has dependency relationships between each package while pip doesn't. Also, "pip" can be used for commercial purpose freely while "conda" cannot be used for commercial for free.
So my question is, how do people check what was used during development? Will there be any license that people can check?
Expect to see clear declaration that "pip" or "conda" was used during development.

Let's clear up some misconceptions first:

difference between them is that "conda" has dependency relationships between each package while pip doesn't

not correct as written here. Both pip and conda resolve dependencies between installed packages

Also, "pip" can be used for commercial purpose freely while "conda" cannot be used for commercial for free.

Also not correct in general. What is not free to use for commercial use are the conda channels maintained by anaconda, but conda itself has a BSD-3 licence and can be used with e.g. the conda forge channel which is under a BSD-3 licence as well
To your question:

So my question is, how do people check what was used during development?

I read it as this scenario: Someone gives you a python code with a requirements.txt and you want to know if they used conda or pip on their system during development.
There is no way that you will be able to tell what they have used during development.
